# How to remove scroll bar from twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-views

I am using django and twiiter bootstrap. In the below code, I am calling a django view inside a bootstrap modal, It is a userena login form - accounts/signin/.
The view renders inside the modal but I am getting a scroll bar, I want to get rid of this scroll bar.

Here is my modal code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#signup').modal({
       remote: '/accounts/signin/',
       show: false
     });
   });
</script>   

    <div class="container">
    <div id="signup" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Sample</a>
             </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>  
     </div>
</div>
```

and then calling the modal here

```
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#signup">Signs Up New</a></li>
```

Is this a correct approach to show the bootstrap modal? How do I get rid of the scroll bars?

Comment: Can someone please help me with this, it has over 30 views but no answers.

Comment: is the content more than that the screen can fit?

Comment: Just found the solution, it's working and it is responsive, stackable, aJAX and more. <http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/>

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'div' with a class 'Modal-body' to hold your content and define the maximum height or maximum width. See example code below.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:800px;">
        Your content here...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```